# In Ruby, what is the class AboutClasses?

Tags: ruby

Searching on 'ruby AboutClasses' gets no hits in SO nor in Google.

```
class Dog
end

fido = Dog.new
puts Dog.inspect
puts fido.inspect
```

The result is

```
AboutClasses::Dog
#<AboutClasses::Dog:0x6255f0>
```

Can you please explain:

- What the term `AboutClasses` is?
- The notation in the second result `#<xxxxx>`. I understand it's an instance, but why put the `#<>` around it?

Comment: What's your development environment? I can't reproduce this in IRB using mac OS X/ruby 1.8

Comment: What version of Ruby? Any gems installed? Haven't seen this before.

Comment: Ditto, can't reproduce on Mac OS X Ruby 1.9

Comment: And the #<> is just default Ruby object output.

Comment: I assume you're doing the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/)?

Comment: Oh .. I messed up. Can I claim 'learners' defense ? Yes I'm working my way through the koans project. I find it an excellent tool for getting my mind into ruby especially if I'm extremely thorough about understanding every single test. But the sad truth is, the class name of the test I am working on is: "AboutClasses" :-(  As far as I'm concerned, my entire question can be removed from SO. Sorry to have missed such an obvious point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Searching GitHub](https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=Ruby&q=aboutclasses&repo=&start_value=2&type=Code) yields a bunch of Ruby source files containing `require 'about_classes'`, all of them in forks of ruby_koans.

In fact, file [about_classes.rb](https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans/blob/master/src/about_classes.rb) file contains a class Dog, named fido, within a class named `AboutClasses`. I'm guessing you have loaded this class or are executing it.

To answer your specific questions about `#<AboutClasses::Dog:0x6255f0>`:

1. The term "AboutClasses" is just a class or module name. You can nest them, so that the outer class or module acts like a namespace. That way, your Dog class doesn't clash with the Dog class in some other gem you've loaded. When you nest them, the names are separated by `::`.
2. The notation `#<ClassName:MemoryAddress>` is just a notation. The hash mark and angle bracket are just there to set it apart from, well, everything else.

Comment: Now that I know that AboutClasses is the very class I'm working in, everything else about my question makes sense. Thank you for the prompt response. The ruby community is awesome and I'm thrilled to be getting on board.

Comment: @WilliamSmith I'm happy to help. I noticed you've asked a few questions but haven't marked any of the answers as "accepted"; check out the [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to see how the site works. And welcome!

Comment: I logged in to meta SO and learned a lot more about marking questions accepted. Then I took care of the questions I had that were still open. Thanks for helping me get up to speed.